# Mixing C++ and Objective-C (Cocoa) resulting in Segmentation Fault

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, cocoa, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to learn my way around Objective-C and read a few tutorials about wrapping Objective-C classes into C++. I got to the following point, where everything compiles without any errors, but when I run the program it results in a "Segmentation Fault".

Ok, let's say I have the following snippets, which I compile with: `g++ -Wall -pedantic -framework Cocoa -x objective-c++ -o test test.mm`. Where am I going wrong?

**test.mm**

```
#include <iostream>
#import "test-osx.m"

struct OpenControllerImpl
{
    OpenController* wrapped;
};

class Panel {
    OpenControllerImpl* impl;

public:
    Panel() :
        impl(new OpenControllerImpl) {
            impl->wrapped = [[OpenController alloc] init];
        }
    ~Panel() {
        [(OpenController*)impl release];
    }
    void open() {
        [(OpenController*)impl doOpen:impl->wrapped];
    }
};

int main() {
    Panel* openPanel = new Panel();
    openPanel->open();
    return 0;
}
```

---

**test-osx.h**

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface OpenController : NSObject {

}

- (void)doOpen:(id)sender;

@end
```

---

**test-osx.m**

```
#import "test-osx.h"
#include <stdio.h>

@implementation OpenController

- (void)doOpen:(id)sender {
    printf("here");
}

@end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[(OpenController*)impl doOpen:impl->wrapped];
```

you are casting the struct holding the Objective-C object to the object type. You have to use

```
[impl->wrapped doOpen:…]
```

You don't need to cast, because `impl->wrapped` already is of pointer to `OpenController` object type.